# Tkinter Grid System: Arranging Elements

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, discord

I am currently coding a program with will tie in with Discord's rich presence, and I am needing to create a GUI for it in Tkinter. The issue is, I cannot understand how to place elements correctly. It has been quite a pain. Here is what I am planning to have the app sort of look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Wox.jpg

However, with my current code, this is how abismal the GUI looks... https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGA9A.jpg

Here is my code:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Matter: A Discord Rich Presence Tool")
root.config(bg='#2C2F33')
root.geometry("560x300")
#root.overrideredirect(1)

# Load images 
loadProfileImage = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="resources/loadprofile.png")
saveProfileImage = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="resources/saveprofile.png")
newProfileImage = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="resources/newprofile.png")


# GUI Hell starts here
topCanvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=600, height=150)
topCanvas.config(bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge', background="#7289DA")

topTextFieldText = tkinter.StringVar(value='Sample top text')
topTextField = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=topTextFieldText)
topTextField.config(borderwidth=0, background="#7289DA")


bottomTextFieldText = tkinter.StringVar(value='Sample bottom text')
bottomTextField = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=bottomTextFieldText)
bottomTextField.config(borderwidth=0, background="#7289DA")


largeIconName = tkinter.StringVar()
largeIconNameField = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=largeIconName)

smallIconName = tkinter.StringVar()
smallIconNameField = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=smallIconName)


applicationIDFieldText = tkinter.StringVar()
applicationIDField = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=applicationIDFieldText)
applicationIDField.config(borderwidth=0, background="#23272A")

largeIconHoverText = tkinter.StringVar()
largeIconHoverTextField = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=largeIconHoverText)
largeIconHoverTextField.config(borderwidth=0, background="#23272A")

smallIconHoverText = tkinter.StringVar()
smallIconHoverTextField = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=smallIconHoverText)
smallIconHoverTextField.config(borderwidth=0, background="#23272A")


#greet_button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Run", command=run)

buttonFrame = tkinter.Frame(height=2, bd=0, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)

newProfileButton = tkinter.Button(root, text="Save to profile", command=save)
newProfileButton.config(image=newProfileImage, borderwidth=0, background="#23272A")


saveButton = tkinter.Button(root, text="Save to profile", command=save)
saveButton.config(image=saveProfileImage, borderwidth=0, background="#23272A")


loadButton = tkinter.Button(root, command=load)
loadButton.config(image=loadProfileImage, borderwidth=0, background="#23272A")


# Grid stuff
topCanvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

applicationIDField.grid(row=3, column=1)
largeIconHoverTextField.grid(row=3, column=2)
smallIconHoverTextField.grid(row=3, column=3)

newProfileButton.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=(20, 5))
saveButton.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=(5, 5))
loadButton.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=(5, 20))

root.mainloop()
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated since I cannot seem to be able to figure out how to use Tkinter's grid to make a layout similar to the images above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to put everything into a single grid. Divide your UI up into sections, and then use the right tool for each section.

#### Start at the root window

I see two major sections to your UI: a top section in blue that has some information, and a bottom section with a black background that has some buttons.

So, I would start by creating those two sections in the root window, and use `pack` to place one on top of the other:

```
topFrame = tk.Frame(root, background="#7289DA")
bottomFrame = tk.Frame(root, background="#2C2F33")

topFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
bottomFrame.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
```

With that, you will now always have the root divided into two colored regions. The above code gives them an equal size. You may one to change the `expand` value to `False` for one or the other, depending on what you want to happen when the user resizes the window.

Don't worry too much about the size, though. It will change once you start adding widgets to each section.

[image]

#### Next, do the bottom section

The bottom also appears to be in two sections: one for inputs and one for buttons. You could use a single grid layout for this whole section, but to illustrate the concept of dividing the UI into sections we'll split the bottom into two. Plus, because everything isn't neatly lined up into rows and columns, this will make things a bit easier.

As I mentioned earlier, you may want to fiddle around with the `expand` option, depending on if you want these frames to resize equally or stay the same size when the user resizes the window.

```
inputFrame = tk.Frame(bottomFrame, background="#2C2F33")
buttonFrame = tk.Frame(bottomFrame, background="#2C2F33")

inputFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
buttonFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Note: if you stop right here and try to run your program, you might not see these frames. During development it sometimes helps to give them distinctive colors to help you visualize. Once you get everything working, you can adjust the colors to their final values.

#### Add the entry widgets

Now we can add the entry widgets to the top half of the bottom section. We can use `grid` here, since everything is lined up neatly. An important step is to give the rows an equal weight so that they grow and shrink together, though you can make it so that only one column resizes if you wish.

I'll also point out that there's no need to use `StringVar` instance. You can, but it adds extra objects to keep track of, which in most cases is not necessary.

```
    label1 = tk.Label(inputFrame, text="APPLICATION ID",
                      foreground="lightgray",
                      background="#2C2F33")
    label2 = tk.Label(inputFrame, text="LARGE IMAGE HOVER",
                      foreground="lightgray",
                      background="#2C2F33")
    label3 = tk.Label(inputFrame, text="SMALL IMAGE HOVER",
                      foreground="lightgray",
                      background="#2C2F33")

    # columns should get extra space equally. Give any extra vertical space
    # to an empty column below the entry widgets
    inputFrame.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2), weight=1)
    inputFrame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

    appIdEntry = tk.Entry(inputFrame, borderwidth=0,
                          highlightthickness=0,
                          background="#23272A", bd=0)
    largeImageEntry = tk.Entry(inputFrame, 
                               highlightthickness=0,
                               background="#23272A", bd=0)
    smallImageEntry = tk.Entry(inputFrame, borderwidth=0,
                               highlightthickness=0,
                               background="#23272A", bd=0)

    label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
    label2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w", padx=10)
    label3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="w")
    appIdEntry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
    largeImageEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew", padx=10)
    smallImageEntry.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="ew")
```

This gives us the following:
[image]

Notice that the top appears to have shrunk. That's only because it's empty. Tkinter is really good about expanding and shrinking things to fit what's inside. Don't worry too much about it. You can tweak things once you get everything working.

### And so on...

I don't want to rewrite your whole program in this answer. The point here is that you should break your UI up into logical chunks, and make each chunk a frame. You are then free to use whatever geometry manager makes the most sense within that frame. Sometimes `grid` is best, sometimes `pack`. In either case, it's much easier to manage a few high level frames than it is to try to cram dozens of widgets into a single grid, especially when there are no clear cut rows and/or columns.

This solution also makes it pretty easy to create functions or classes for each section. For example, your main program might look like:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
top = topSection(root)
bottom = bottomSection(root)
```

By doing so, if you decide to completely redesign one section of the UI, you can do so without worrying that you'll mess up the layout in the other sections, since each frame is mostly independent of any other frame.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I have finally finished coding the application, and I would just like to thank you for the code samples! It gave me a lot more insight into how to use tkinter, and I managed to finish up the application's GUI! Here's a semi-final screenshot of the app: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nkomarn/SpigotImages/master/Capture.JPG. I ended up changing the color scheme (and layout) quite a bit, but it worked out well in the end. Many thanks for all the help once again!

Answer (score 1):

First you have to explain to the grid geometry manager that you want the canvas to span all three columns:

```
topCanvas.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)
```

Widgets do not automatically expand to fill the entire column (or row) if you don't specify it and it will center itself in a cell if you dont specify where you want it with `sticky`:

```
newProfileButton.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=(20, 5), sticky='w')
saveButton.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=(5, 5), sticky='w')
loadButton.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=(5, 20), sticky='w')
```

This will hopefully give you something to play with although it's not a complete answer.

Here is a good tutorial: [Getting Tkinter Grid Sizing Right the first time](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Tkinter-Getting-Tkinter-Grid-Sizing-Right-the-first-time?pid=3991)